# Android phonegap application issue with hardware back button

Tags: android, cordova

I have a problem with the Phonegap Android application with the back button in some Android devices.[image]

[image]

In the Pic when I press application's back button(Red color button), it is not working and the phone's home is working. This is in particular of some Android devices which is having the hardware buttons in main screen.

Now the question is how to stop the phonegap application before the hardware buttons. Means I wat to stop the application top of those device buttons, because I need those buttons also for the application

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to add a `margin-bottom` to that red button or to create another element at the end of the page with the same height of the button to avoid such problems.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but in Samsung devices if we use margin-bottom that my cause issue like application will move some what up. right?